# Subtracting Time in PHP to get Difference in Seconds

Tags: php, mysql, time, subtraction

I want to figure out the difference in time by seconds. I keep getting 0 as a results and wants to know if someone could assist me. The times will be pulled from a database.

Here is an example of what I want to be able to do.

```
$TimeStart = "04:30:45 am";
$TimeEnd = "04:31:46 am";
$Difference = $TimeEnd - $TimeStart . "seconds";
```

I know this is not a very illustrated example and I know it is probably not that simple.

Here is the code that is currently on my site now:

```
$TimeStart = strtotime($VisitsRow['TimeStart']);
$TimeEnd = strtotime($VisitsRow['TimeEnd']);
$TimeDifference = ($TimeEnd - $TimeStart);
if ($VisitsRow['TimeEnd'] == "") {
    $Timeto = "Incomplete";
} else {
    if ($TimeDifference <= 60) {
        $Timeto = "< a minute";
    } else if ($TimeDifference <= 0) {
        $Timeto = "< a second";
    } else {
        $Timeto = round($TimeDifference, 2)." seconds";
    }
    if ($TimeDifference >= 60) {
        $MinutesDiff = $TimeDifference / 60;
        $Timeto = round($MinutesDiff, 2)." minutes";
    }
}
```

I have simply tried the example of what I want above and am getting a negative number. This is why I am needing assistance.

Comment: Have you considered using the DateTime class? http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: I am able too but when I add date($Start____) it doesn't change anything. I am getting a negative number or 0 when there are minutes in difference.

Comment: I have used the DateTime class but it breaks the page.

Comment: Your code works fine, given the example values.  Show us `$VisitsRow` when you are "getting a negative number or 0".

Comment: Here is one of them: Time Start 15:30:30 pm Time End 15:36:59 pm When I subtract these two I get a -15.

Comment: Using 24 hour time with am/pm does not make sense to PHP, see [Time formats](http://php.net/datetime.formats.time).

Comment: What does `'15:30:30 pm'` mean?  Surely it's either `'15:30:30'` or `'3:30:30 pm'`?  What is the data type of your `TimeStart` and `TimeEnd` columns?

Comment: I'm trying your suggest Salathe and Will post once I see if it works or not. Thank you. and Eggyal that time is military time. I didn't notice it before but it may be what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for helping me solve this. My problem was that it was gathering the times in 24 hr format and not the standard. Once I solved this everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy with `strtotime`:

```
$TimeStart = strtotime("04:30:45");
$TimeEnd = strtotime("04:31:46");

$Difference = ($TimeEnd - $TimeStart) . " seconds";
```

But, if you need it to be more dynamic, through SQL, you can subtract the two date fields with this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,TimeEnd,TimeStart) AS TimeDifference FROM myTable
```

(Note you can change `MINUTE` to another time metric if you want)